# TFS2010 Branching vcxproj not updating SccProjectName

Tags: visual-c++

So, I've got a native vc++ application that we currently have stored in TFS2010 (no SP), and we have finnally gotten to the point after the migration from TFS2005 to TFS2010 where we need to branch the code...

After branching the code, which now in TFS2010 does everything on the server and no longer leaves all of the files checked out on the client machine, and which also did NOT throw any errors of any sort...  if we try to open the branch copy of the application we get an error:

"There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source control information about some project(s) and the information in the project's files(s). ... blah blah blah"

Now this error is being thrown because inside the project file (vcxproj) the SccProjectName value was not updated as part of the branching, so it is still pointing to full path of the trunk source location.  Although when it throws this error it will prompt for a check-out and will update the value to the correct value... but it's will be annoying for it to happen every time we branch and there's no way to change it before it throws the error.

Online in [various places](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/786d7d3e-5182-4452-b49b-3436de6f9c36/) the 'solution' (I use this term loosely because it doesn't work...) is to change the SccProjectName to "SAK" so that it will use the value in the mssccprj.scc hint file, however the TFS plugin doesn't use a mssccprj.scc hint file... so it will continue to throw the error...

So is there another solution to this issue? or does anybody know if the TFS2010 SP1 fixes this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when moving code around in TFS 2010. Here is the solution that I found to work:

> It is easier to do this by selecting the solution in Solution Explorer, going to File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control and then unbinding everything.  Close the dialog, then re-open it and rebind everything.  Save the changes and compare the VCXPROJ files now.  The server path and the rest of the TFS info has been removed and replaced with SAK.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/786d7d3e-5182-4452-b49b-3436de6f9c36/

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have put that answer in here myself after Keith answered my answer on the MSDN site.  The key here is that ALL of the bindings in the .sln need changed to SAK, not just the one.

Comment: Key here is to Unbind, CLOSE the dialog and then open it and rebind.  I tried these steps a few times before realizing the poster on the Microsoft site clearly said 'close the dialog'.  As strange as it is, the fix will not work unless you do.

Comment: My issue is that, once I do that, effectively, my files now have SAK in them, but the source control does not pick-up on it, so I can not checkin the files, source control think they have not changed.

Comment: This also worked for a `.sqlproj`.  VS2012 has an extra expanding menu-item "Advanced", so: "File" | "Source Control" | ""Advanced" | "Change Source Control".